# Querying Data Using Existing Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, excel

I have a spreadsheet that lists customers, their supervisor information, and special feature codes that are listed on their account at the time the report was created.

I need to add a column to this sheet that lists the last active date that these codes were populated on the customer account.

I'm aware of how pull the info when the features were last active.  However, I need to base my query based on these specific accounts and codes.  What family of SQL Clauses can I use to read these preexisting values and return a corresponding date value?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous.  How are you populating the spreadsheet?  Are you using an ETL application like SSIS or creating an Excel output from a SQL query in your database?

If you are populating an existing Excel spreadsheet, then create in that spreadsheet a new column called "Last Active Date" in preparation for populating it from the source.

If you are pulling the data from a database source, then there may be an associated history or archive table where you can find the pre-existing codes along with their corresponding dates.  Here your database administrator and/or developer will be better equiped to assist you in navigating the database architecture.  If the codes are no longer available in the source database, then no special SQL CLAUSE will assist.  You cannot retrieve that which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Kosh.  I apologize for my ambiguity, I seem to always leave out details in hopes of keeping the reader's interest.  I'd like to leave a same attachment but don't see where I can attach a file to my reply.

Comment: I'm actually using Teradata and copying the results to a spreadsheet.  So the 2nd option you listed I suppose. 

There is a table that I can tie the phone number of the customer to the speacial feature codes I referenced.  The problem is finding that, it's taking an existing list of numbers and using that in my query to find the corresponding "last active date" for a feature associated with that number.  If you can direct me to the process for attaching a file, I'd be happy to show you what I'm looking at.